# Работа с json-файлом большого размера

Tags: json, angularjs

Имеется json файл, который весит 255 Мб.
Там очень большой массив объектов.

При работе с $http.get запросом в AngularJS он пытается его загрузить полностью.
Это не очень мне нравится с точки зрения производительности.

Можно ли как-то дробить этот файл или каким-то способом не загружать его полностью?

Или же все действия с ним, а именно запросы на выборку определенных данных, лучше делать другим средствами?

Подскажите как лучше поступить?

Comment: Сервер ваш? Или сторонний?

Comment: @AGS17 Локальный сервер (Websorm), на котором разрабатываю приложение, вообще отказывается его загружать и с ним работать. Продакшн сервер не мой, но там с загрузкой такого объема проблем нету. Но это веб-приложение и и оно явно будет жрать трафик, пока загрузит полностью ресурс.